# FFMpeg high CPU Utilization

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

I am trying a trancoding system based on ffmpeg and Quadro P4000 gpu using h264_nvenc. Bud I have also a very high cpu usage while I start a transcoding. on 4 sd streams I have 80+ % cpu usage on 4core I5 with 3,5 GHz. GPU usage based on nvidia-smi is around 3%. What is wrong?
The system is running on Ubuntu 16.0.3.

I tried upgrade to newest video driver, also tried use other ffmpeg based solutions with the same result.

Any idea? 
Thank you
Dave

Comment: Is there any reason you would expect not to have high CPU usage for such a highly intensive task?

Comment: Becouse I thought that if I use gpu that is supported with ffmpeg, I move most of tasks to GPU. But the GPU runs only for few % and CPU is still overloaded.

Comment: Hard to provide input without seeing your command and the complete console output (assuming you're using the `ffmpeg` cli tool).

Comment: Prebuilt ffmpeg or did you build it yourself?